# angularjs json parsing issue

Tags: json, angularjs, view

Using an ajax request I receive the following json data:

```
{ 
    "status" : "success", 
    "xplist" : [
        { "rank" : "1", "username" : "test1", "xp" : "2500" },
        { "rank" : "2", "username" : "test2", "xp" : "2200" },
        { "rank" : "3", "username" : "test3", "xp" : "1900" }
     ]
 }
```

In my controller I created empty data variable

```
 $scope.data = {};
```

And assign the json data to it like this:

```
$scope.data.xpresult = data;
```

Then in my view I try to use ng-repeat to get the items out:

```
<li ng-repeat="xp in data.xpresult.xplist">                                             
     <div class="listItem">
         <div class="left">                                                          
             <p>{{xp.rank}}</p>
         </div>              
         <div class="middle">
             <p style="padding: 8px 46px 0px 0px;margin:0">{{xp.username}}</p>
             <p style="margin:0px">{{xp.xp}}</p>
          </div>          
    </div>
</li>
```

I also tried the to repeat the following instead:

```
data.xpresult.0.xplist
```

Also tried to put the data in a variable and stringify the result again:

```
var xpdata = JSON.parse(data);
$scope.data.xpresult = JSON.stringify(xpdata.xplist);
```

But unfortunately this didn't work either.

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to get this out properly or what I am doing wrong?

*Update*

The controller is as following:

```
angular.module('AndriodApp')

.controller('ExperienceController', function($scope,md5){

$scope.data = {};

$scope.getTop50 = function(uid,uname) {
    var token = md5.createHash("test"+uid+uname+"test");
    var postdata = { messagetype: "getexperience", userid: uid, securitytoken: token };
    $.post("http://127.0.0.1/backend/jiomsg.php",postdata)
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
            $scope.data.xpresult = data;
    });
}

$scope.getTop50("1","Gerard");
});
```

Comment: may be data.xpresult.data.xplist. if "data" is from promise.

Comment: Where is your $http request defined ? 
Can you show us the call with $scope.data.xpresult = data;
Are the HTML template & $scope assignment into same Ctrl?  your html seems good (big code)

Comment: Updated my post with the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You're sending a request and receiving a response behind the back of AngularJS, which has no idea you have modified the scope, and that the expressions in the page should thus be reevaluated.

Use the $http service, and everything will go fine:

```
$http.post("http://127.0.0.1/backend/jiomsg.php", postdata)
    .success(function(data) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        $scope.data.xpresult = data;
    });
```

Or, if using jquery is really necessary for whatever reason, make sure angular knows about the received response:

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1/backend/jiomsg.php",postdata)
    .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        $scope.data.xpresult = data;
        $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: I used jquery because the $http.post didn't return any data. I tried your snippet there as well but it returns empty.  I have added the $scope.$apply(); but it still won't display. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Use the debugger and inspect the value of data. Is it anobject or is it a string? If it is a string, you'll have to parse it with angular.fromJson().

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. It was indeed a string that needed to convert to json.